# Why do I have zero as contour value with pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

I am making a contour plot, and the MWE below produces the result
[image]

i.e.the contour lines with value 10^{-6} and below are simply marked by 0. Did I hit some number representation limit?

```
\documentclass[A4]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableset{%
    col sep=semicolon,
    x index=0,
    y index=1,
    header=false
}%

\begin{filecontents*}{XYZ.csv}
   2016; 1;       33e-9
   2016; 2;      199e-9
   2016; 3;      966e-9
   2016; 4;      110e-9

   2015; 1;      199e-9
   2015; 2;      966e-9
   2015; 3;      110e-9
   2015; 4;      104e-9

   2014; 1;      199e-9
   2014; 2;      965e-9
   2014; 3;      110e-9
   2014; 4;      104e-9

   2006; 1;     2349e-9
   2006; 2;     6528e-9
   2006; 3;    18405e-9
   2006; 4;    17250e-9

   1993; 1;  1167453e-9
   1993; 2;  2376539e-9
   1993; 3;  2262076e-9
   1993; 4;  2262076e-9

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[view = {0}{90}] ,zmode=log, log base=10 ]%
        \addplot3[%
            surf,shader=interp,opacity=0.8
        ] table {XYZ.csv};
        \addplot3[%
            contour gnuplot={levels={.0000001,.000001,.00001,.0001,.001,.01,.1},draw color=black},
        ] table {XYZ.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the question in the title (about `\input`) doesn't seem connected to the question in the text (about 10^{-6}) ?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. In the meantime I learned that if I do not list data in {filecontents*}, it makes the functionality I was looking for. Now I correct the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of the options of your axis are ignored due to am extra `]`. As a consequence, your axis has a linear scale -- and on a linear scale, the small numbers are squashed to zero. You can still reconfigure the displayed range of the contour lines (see second image below).

As soon as you really have a log scale, the contour lines are computed in log coordinates. Pgfplots is not very smart in this context and one has to reconfigure the number printer if one wants non-log numbers:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableset{%
    col sep=semicolon,
    x index=0,
    y index=1,
    header=false
}%

\begin{filecontents*}{XYZ.csv}
   2016; 1;       33e-9
   2016; 2;      199e-9
   2016; 3;      966e-9
   2016; 4;      110e-9

   2015; 1;      199e-9
   2015; 2;      966e-9
   2015; 3;      110e-9
   2015; 4;      104e-9

   2014; 1;      199e-9
   2014; 2;      965e-9
   2014; 3;      110e-9
   2014; 4;      104e-9

   2006; 1;     2349e-9
   2006; 2;     6528e-9
   2006; 3;    18405e-9
   2006; 4;    17250e-9

   1993; 1;  1167453e-9
   1993; 2;  2376539e-9
   1993; 3;  2262076e-9
   1993; 4;  2262076e-9

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{
        contour/log labels/.style={
            /pgfplots/contour/label node code/.code={
                \node {$10^{\pgfmathprintnumber{##1}}$};
            },
        },
    }
    \begin{axis}[view = {0}{90} ,zmode=log, log basis z=10 ]%
        \addplot3[%
            surf,shader=interp,opacity=0.8
        ] table {XYZ.csv};
        \addplot3[%
            contour gnuplot={
                levels={.0000001,.000001,.00001,.0001,.001,.01,.1},
                draw color=black,
                log labels,
            },
        ] table {XYZ.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is the graphics in linear scale with more precision for the number printer of contour labels. By default, it rounds to 3 signficant digits.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableset{%
    col sep=semicolon,
    x index=0,
    y index=1,
    header=false
}%

\begin{filecontents*}{XYZ.csv}
   2016; 1;       33e-9
   2016; 2;      199e-9
   2016; 3;      966e-9
   2016; 4;      110e-9

   2015; 1;      199e-9
   2015; 2;      966e-9
   2015; 3;      110e-9
   2015; 4;      104e-9

   2014; 1;      199e-9
   2014; 2;      965e-9
   2014; 3;      110e-9
   2014; 4;      104e-9

   2006; 1;     2349e-9
   2006; 2;     6528e-9
   2006; 3;    18405e-9
   2006; 4;    17250e-9

   1993; 1;  1167453e-9
   1993; 2;  2376539e-9
   1993; 3;  2262076e-9
   1993; 4;  2262076e-9

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[view = {0}{90}]%
        \addplot3[%
            surf,shader=interp,opacity=0.8
        ] table {XYZ.csv};
        \addplot3[%
            contour gnuplot={
                levels={.0000001,.000001,.00001,.0001,.001,.01,.1},
                draw color=black,
                contour label style={/pgf/number format/std},
            },
        ] table {XYZ.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

PS
The triangle artifacts do not really belong to the picture... seems that `convert -density 150` produces these artifacts.