# PGFplots contour gnuplot call results in empty .table file

Tags: gnuplot, pgfplots

I am trying to reproduce the following code from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/330544/59521) which i paste here with the fixes suggested by @TikZling for convenience:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableset{%
    col sep=semicolon,
    x index=0,
    y index=1,
    header=false
}%

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{XYZ.csv}
   2016; 1;       33e-9
   2016; 2;      199e-9
   2016; 3;      966e-9
   2016; 4;      110e-9

   2015; 1;      199e-9
   2015; 2;      966e-9
   2015; 3;      110e-9
   2015; 4;      104e-9

   2014; 1;      199e-9
   2014; 2;      965e-9
   2014; 3;      110e-9
   2014; 4;      104e-9

   2006; 1;     2349e-9
   2006; 2;     6528e-9
   2006; 3;    18405e-9
   2006; 4;    17250e-9

   1993; 1;  1167453e-9
   1993; 2;  2376539e-9
   1993; 3;  2262076e-9
   1993; 4;  2262076e-9
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[view = {0}{90}]%
        \addplot3[%
            surf,shader=interp,opacity=0.8
        ] table {XYZ.csv};
        \addplot3[%
            contour gnuplot={
                levels={.0000001,.000001,.00001,.0001,.001,.01,.1},
                draw color=black,
                contour label style={/pgf/number format/std},
            },
        ] table {XYZ.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

According to the original answer, the output should be like this:
[image]

Compiling via

```
$ lualatex --shell-escape contour.tex
```

yields this warning

```
Package pgfplots Warning: the current plot has no coordinates (or all have been
 filtered away) on input line 56.
```

and the `.table` file returned from gnuplot is likewise empty:

```
$ cat contour_contourtmp0.table 

# Surface 0 of 1 surfaces

# Curve title: ""contour_contourtmp0.dat""
```

Im using TeXlive 2020 on Arch Linux, `$ gnuplot` is available on the command line.

Comment: The problem is that the `filecontents` stuff has changed. You no longer need `\usepackage{filecontents}` and you should start the file contents with `\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{XYZ.csv}` and them with `\end{filecontents}`. (You'd also benefit from `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}` or `\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}` and do not need to load `pgfplots` twice.)

Comment: I've incorporated you remarks, but it does not change anything - unsurprisingly, since the `.dat` file exported by PGFplots for gnuplot did contain the correct data in the first place.

Comment: I've checked the contour examples from http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/contours.html and they work. Hence, the error is not with my installation but something probably broke in PGFplots.

Comment: Hmmh, in my case the changes made a nonworking file working. OK, at least this problem is ruled out for your question.

Comment: So the above code produces the desired output for you?

Comment: Yes. The shading is slightly different but this may be viewer-dependent.

Comment: Could you possibly run `gnuplot contour_contourtmp0.script` on the command line and tell me if you then get actual data in `contour_contourtmp0.table`. If so, this question is off topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my system had a default `~/.gnuplot` configuration file in the home directory that specified `set datafile separator comma`.

This caused the data from `contour_contourtmp0.dat` to be interpreted as comma separated which inevitably yielded no valid data points.